# Querying a Many-to-Many relation with LINQ

Tags: .net, sql, linq, many-to-many

I use EF 4.1 where three tables are mapped in a m-n relationship. I am new to Linq so this will be an easy one for most of you.

The tables are Users -> Users_Rights_Map -> Rights

...a classic m-n.

I'd like to find all users that have a RightID of 1, for example.

```
  var r = from u context.Users 
  where u.Rights.Select(r => r.RightID == 1)
  select u;
```

...doesn't work.

What does the correct LINQ query look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong (`in` is not in your query) and you should use some conditional function for making condition not using `select`.

```
var r = from u in context.Users 
  where u.Rights.Any(r => r.RightID == 1)
  select u;
```

**Edit:** for linq startup and training I think is good for you to see [101 linq sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).
For `Any` You can see Quantifiers, there are samples, like `Any`, `All`. Specially your case included there.

Comment: Thanks. I have 101 Linq samples, have not seen or understood the Any() yet.

Comment: @John, There are some operator like this, instead of any you can use `FirstOrDefaul(r => r.RightID == 1) != null` It will be converted to exactly same sql query, In fact `Any` searchs for existence of some item with specific condition, `FirstOrDefault`, finds some item with specific condition, and if you convert your FirstOrDefault to bool, it will be same as `Any`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
  var users = from u in context.Users 
  where u.Rights.Any(r => r.RightID == 1)
  select u;
```

Comment: @SaeedAmiri can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: It means you should change: `from u context.Users` to `from u in context.Users`